# Hide coordinates for google maps

Tags: google-maps, hide, coordinates

I would like to point an icon on google maps, but I was also like to hide exact coordinates from the source code.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could use static maps api (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/). You would create a request to an api on the server side, save the resulting image with your own file name and display just a static image to the user from your server. I am pretty sure though this would violate Google Terms of Use....

Comment: How about using a handler to retrieve coordinates? Is that possible?